# AWS - How to Connect Elastic Beanstalk to Private RDS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, amazon-elb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Can someone please clearly explain in a step-by-step guide and in simple terms from start to finish how to properly setup a private RDS instance that connects to:

1. Elastic Beanstalk instance where the the environment is using a load balancing, auto scaling web server environment using PHP as it’s platform.
2. MySQL Workbench

Side note, the EB and RDS instance(s) are all in the same VPC. I suppose in reality this may be more of a how to properly setup and connect IAM profiles and roles question.

In essence, I want to restrict all internet access from the RDS instance, while still allowing my EB instance or other resources i.e other EC2 instances (all located in the same VPC) the ability to connect to the RDS instance, while also allowing me to use (connect to) a DB tool like MySQL Workbench.

Elastic Beanstalk Security Questions:

- Instance Profile: `How should I setup/config this role and it’s associated policy`
- Service Profile: `How should I setup/config this role and it’s associated policy`

RDS Security Questions:

- VPC Security Groups: `How should I setup/config this security group(s) to allow access from EB instance, other specified resources (EC2), and MySQL Workbench`

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for the response. I'm trying to prevent internet access to my RDS instance to provide greater security measures and I've tried playing around with IAM profiles and security groups but I still haven't got the hang of them yet, which is why I posted this question to find out the best or recommended way of setting this up.

Comment: Specifically, what did you try? If you tell us what you tried, we can tell you what went wrong.

Comment: Give us more detail on the following; What is running on the Elastic Beanstalk (e.g. Java, PHP, etc.)?  How are you connecting to RDS (e.g. AWS RDS Client, JDBC, etc.)?  What security measures are you currently / trying to employ (e.g. role / user based credentials, IP-based rules, database user-based access)?  There are so many ways to skin that cat, that if you're more detailed, you're more likely to get a higher quality and faster response.

Comment: Hi Brooks and Matt, after thinking about your questions, I have revised my original  question to hopefully provide you both with more details about what I'm trying to accomplish. Thank you for your time and responses.